# How to download gcc v4.4.3 version on Ubuntu 20?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, gem5

I am following this tutorial https://github.com/tukl-msd/DRAMPower which gcc- v4.4.3 is one of the requirement.
How I can download it on ubuntu 20

Comment: I'd try the latest GCC first. *If* it doesn't work, and you're unable to make it work, then install the old GCC.

Comment: latest GCC do not work

Answer (score 0):

As shown at; https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu/1163021#1163021 there is not even a PPA for it, so your only choices are to compile it yourself, or use some shady PPA.

These two questions are similar:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235819/ubuntu-20-04-gcc-version-lower-than-gcc-7
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229774/how-to-use-an-older-version-of-gcc

This question is better suited for: https://askubuntu.com/ BTW.